# GCC Preprocessor how to replace #define with empty line

Tags: javascript, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to use the GCC Preprocessor with Javascript source code.

I would like to keep the line numbers the same between the original source and the output. So that if there are any errors in the JS code in the output, the line numbers should match the line numbers in the original file.

I would like achieve the output below from this input:

```
Line 1 // comment
Line 2 #define ASDF 'asdf'
Line 3
Line 4 var asdf = ASDF
```

Output:

```
Line 1 // comment
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4 var asdf = 'asdf'
```

How could I achieve the above?

So far I have tried:

`/usr/bin/cpp -P -undef -Wundef -std=c99 -nostdinc -Wtrigraphs -fdollars-in-identifiers -traditional-cpp -E -C $INFILE -o $OUTFILE`

The `-traditional-cpp` preserves whitespace, and the `-E` preserves comments.

Is it possible to replace all lines with preprocessor directives with empty lines?

Answer (score 1):

Running

```c
gcc -xc file.c -E -P -o file.txt
```

against (3 lines)

```c
#define ASDF 'asdf'

var asdf = ASDF
```

yields (1 line)

```
var asdf = 'asdf'
```

Thus it's not that all requested lines are empty, but they were removed entirely. Maybe that fits your purpose? With `-traditional-cpp`, there are's bunch of empty lines, dunno where they come from though... Adding `-v` to see which sub-commands are issued by `gcc` prints:

```
.../cc1 -E -quiet -v -P -o file.txt <irrelevant-options>
```

---

**Addendum 1:** In order to preserve comments, add `-C`

`cpp file.c -E -P -C -nostdinc`

I needed the `-nostdinc`  because otherwise gcc would include `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h`.  However blank lines are still removed.

Comment: Thank you, however I would like to keep the line numbers the same between the original source and the output. So that if there are any errors in the JS code in the output, the line numbers should match the line numbers in the original file. (I'll update the question with this.) Without  the parameter `-traditional-cpp` it removes all empty lines and removes all extra whitespace.

Comment: I have added an example comment to the example in the question. The comments should be preserved, since they can be multiline comments, and if they are removed, the line numbers won't match, so the comments should be kept too.

Comment: @gregn3 : I added a remark that `-C` retains comments.

Comment: I created a Perl script to create intermediate input to the preprocessor, that will result in the correct output .I have posted it below. It's a work-in-progress, but I wanted to share it.

Comment: I found the original command ( `/usr/bin/cpp -P -undef -Wundef -std=c99 -nostdinc -Wtrigraphs -fdollars-in-identifiers -C` ) [here](http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/js-cpp.html) , however it's not enough by itself, to preserve line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Perl script to create an intermediate file that creates and ensures the correct number of empty lines, so that after the preprocessor runs, the output will have the same number of lines, and matching line numbers as the input.

It's a draft version and has some unfinished/unused parts, but it already works to solve the main issue in the question above, and might be useful to others in the same situation.
I have only tested it minimally so far.

I use it with a Makefile, an example posted below.

**keep_preprocessor_emptylines.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


# example usage of PPEXTRALINES:
#
#  #define SOMEFUNC__PPEXTRALINES_4_ \
#  function hello () \
#  { \
#    console.log ('hello world') \
#  } 
#
# # the above will be replaced with a single line
# SOMEFUNC__PPEXTRALINES_4_
#
#

# expecting the input filename on a line by itself preceding the input lines
my $input_filename;


my $multiline_sig = '__PPEXTRALINES_(\d+)_';

my $ensure_n_empty_lines_follow = 0;

my $line_num = -1 -1; # -1 gives the correct line numbers in the error message below... intended 0 here originally
                      # the second -1 is for the input filename that precedes the input


while (<STDIN>)
{
    $line_num++;

    if ($line_num == -1)
    {
        $input_filename = $_;
        chomp $input_filename;
        next;
    }


    my $is_empty_line = ($_ =~ /^\s*$/gm);
    if ($ensure_n_empty_lines_follow > 0)
    {
        if (!$is_empty_line)
        {
            chomp;
            my $n = $ensure_n_empty_lines_follow;
            my $es = $n == 1 ? '' : 's';
            print STDERR '(' . __FILE__ . "): \"$input_filename\": error on line $line_num: expected $n empty line$es here, but found non-empty line\nline: \"$_\"\n";
            exit -1
        }
        else
        {
            # ok ,remove this empty line, because it will be replaced by the contents of the preceding macro
            $ensure_n_empty_lines_follow--;
            next;
        }
    }

    #my $is_directiveline = ($_ =~ /^\s*([#!][ \t]{1,}?([A-z]{2,})[\s]{1,}?([A-z]{2,}[\s]{1,}?)?)([\\(]?[^\s\\)]{1,}[\\)]?)?/);
    my $is_directiveline = ($_ =~ /^\s*[#!][ \t]*([A-z]{2,})\s+([A-z0-9_]{2,})\b/);
    my $directive_name = $1;
    my $second_word = $2;
    my $has_multiline_sig = ($_ =~ /$multiline_sig/);
    my $n_extra_lines = int ($1);

    if ($has_multiline_sig)
    {
        if ($is_directiveline)
        {
            my $is_the_definition = (($directive_name eq 'define') && ($second_word =~ /$multiline_sig/));

            if ($is_the_definition)
            {
                # insert that number of lines + 1 above it
                print ("\n" x ($n_extra_lines + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                # otherwise it might be used in another macro, we should ignore it there

                # print one empty line above it, since it's a macro line
                print ("\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {   # is a usage
            # ensure at least ($n_extra_lines + 1) empty lines follow it.
            # fail with error if not.
            # then remove those empty lines, so they will be replaced by the macro's contents


            # this seems unnecessary, only would be needed if the macro expands to multiple lines, which the example above doesn't
            # uncomment the below line to enable ensuring enough empty lines follow the macro
            # might need to create a new special name for these
            # the current PPEXTRALINES one only supports a multiple-line definition, but single line expansion
            #$ensure_n_empty_lines_follow = $n_extra_lines + 1;
        }
    }
    elsif ($is_directiveline)
    {   # other macro line
        # print one empty line above it
        print ("\n");
    }

    print $_;   
}
```

The Makefile processes all files with **.P.js** extension and converts them into **.js** files by running the intermediate script and the preprocessor on it. The intermediate files are created temporarily with a **.Pke.js** extension.

**Makefile**

```
%.js : %.P.js
    echo "$<" | cat - "$<" | ./keep_preprocessor_emptylines.pl > "$(patsubst %.P.js,%.Pke.js,$<)" 
    /usr/bin/cpp -P -undef -Wundef -std=c99 -nostdinc -Wtrigraphs -fdollars-in-identifiers -traditional-cpp -E -C "$(patsubst %.P.js,%.Pke.js,$<)" -o "$@" 
    rm "$(patsubst %.P.js,%.Pke.js,$<)"
```

I invoke the Makefile with this command, maybe it could be added into the Makefile itself, but works for me anyway:

```
make `ls -1 *.P.js | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/\.P\.js$/\.js/; print $_'`
```